# Issues with creating XSLT

Tags: html, xslt

Given the following examples of input and output XML documents, write an XSLT
program that will transform between them. The output is an HTML document.! !

Sample Input XML document:!

```
  <library name="Library Name 1" address="Address">!
   <libraryItems>!
  <libraryItem type="book" id="123" isbn="123" title="Title1" summary="Summary1"!
   publisher="Publisher1" published="1/2/12" barcode="Code1" 
           rfid="RFID1" added="1/2/12">!
        <author name="Author Name1"/>!
         </libraryItem>!
     ! ...any number of items of type book...!
       <libraryItem type="cd" id="345" title="Title3" tracks="Tracks1" genre="Genre1"!
     ! barcode="Code3" rfid="RFID3" added="1/2/12"/>!
     ! ...any number of items of type cd...!
    </libraryItems>!
  <accounts>!
   <account number="234" state="ACTIVE">!
       <patron firstName="Firstname1" lastName="Lastname1" address="Address1"/>!
    <borrows item="123"/>!
     ! ...any number of borrows...!
      </account>!
      ! ...any number of accounts...!
     </accounts>!
       </library>! !
```

Sample Output HTML document:!

```
<h1>Borrowed Items</h1>!
<table><tr>! <th>Library</th><th>Patron</th><th>Borrowing</th>! </tr>!
! <tr>! <td>Library Name 1</td><td>Firstname1 Lastname1</td><td>Title1</td></tr>!
! <tr>! <td>Library Name 1</td><td>Firstname2 Lastname2</td><td>Title2</td></tr>!
! ...one row for every borrowed item...!
</table>
```

This is the solution that gave three errors:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
 <h1>Borrowed Items</h1>!
<table>
<tr>! 
<th>Library</th>
<th>Patron</th>
<th>Borrowing</th>!
 </tr>!

<xsl:for-each select="//library/libraryitems/libraryitem | //library/accounts/account">

 <tr>
<td>library name 1</td>      
  <td><xsl:value-of select="firstName"/><xsl:value-of select="lastName"/></td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>    </tr>
 </xsl:for-each>
</table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What corrections should i make?

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: write an XSLT program that will transform between them.

Comment: That is a **task**, not a question.

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems on that solution is how you are accessing the XML tag attribute, XSL uses [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/) to navigate the XML structure, that is very similar to file system nav syntax, imagine you are in a directory and you want to go up or down the path. when you have an attribute you need to put @attributeName so first name would actually be @firstName but you need to be in the right tag.

Also when you have to match the borrowed ID with the title id you just need to navigate back using '..' and then navigate to the libraryItem you want, for the match I find it better to use the 'key' tag  though.

Take a look on the below solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:key name="title" match="libraryItem" use="@id"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <body>
    <h1>Borrowed Items</h1>
    <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Library</th>
        <th>Patron</th>
        <th>Borrowing</th>
    </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="library/accounts/account">
            <xsl:for-each select="borrows">
                <tr>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="../../../@name"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of  select="../patron/@firstName"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="../patron/@lastName"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="key('title', @item)/@title"/></td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each> 
        </xsl:for-each>    
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to solve it? If yes you can share how and we can guide you on the path, if not

XSLT isn't that hard, it's basically a CSS for XML, you should take a look here for starters: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/default.asp

and here if you are not familiar with xpath: 
http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/

And then refine your question for a more specific answer.

Comment: I am not able to understand that how do i implement it,is it using nodes or table

Comment: It works in this way: you have your XML input and you have a XSL file. You will link the XSL file to your XML the way explained in the first link. The XSL file has the power to transform the XML in anything you want. So in your case HTM. Begin by linking your empty XSL file to your XML and view on thr browser, you'll see an empty page, then go gradually add your things, create a template (check the link) in XSL file, then first add the HTML + body + h1 tag view the result and keep going gradually adding stuff until you have what you are looking for. XSLT is actually fun once you understand it!